# Does an Indian need a transit visa for a long layover in Dubai? Does Emirates provide transit accommodation in economy class?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, layovers, dxb, emirates

I am travelling from Copenhagen to Kolkata. I have a 13 hour layover in Dubai.

- Do I need a visa for a layover of this length?
- Do Emirates provide anything for a layover of this length?

Comment: My Indian citizenship and i have a flight from Copenhegan to Dubai ( in emirates ) which will reach at 11.55 PM in dubai and my next flight is from Dubai to Kolkata( In Emirates ) at 1:15 PM next day.

Comment: What class are you flying? I've never had an airline provide anything for long layovers, but I only fly economy class. If you're flying Business class or above it might be different.

Comment: I am traveling in Economy Class

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to apply for a 48 hour transit visa that will allow you to leave the airport if you so wish. You are responsible for your own activities during this layover. The airline does not arrange anything other than the visa sponsorship.

> Transit visas for 48 hours are issued free of charge to passengers transiting through the UAE’s airports. You need to apply for the visa in advance through a UAE-based airline. This visa is not extendable, nor renewable. The validity of the visa is 48 hours from entry into the UAE, and you must leave the UAE within 48 hours from arrival.

*[source](https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/visiting-and-exploring-the-uae/transit-visa)*